# jquery plugin loaded but 'inaccesible' in WebControl

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, web-controls

I'm having trouble making a fixedTableHeader. I've found a jQuery plugin that works fine in simple test. But I need to include it as an embedded resource in a WebControl.

So I'v registered the scripts in the Assembly.cs and set them to be 'embedded resources'

In the WebControl they are registered like this:

```
 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "jquery",  Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "LRGrid.jquery_min.js"));

 var fixedScript = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "LRGrid.jquery_fixedheadertable.js");

 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "fixedheadertable", fixedScript);

 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "jquery",  Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "LRGrid.jquery.tablescroll.js"));
```

Then in order to call the script I do:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "SetTable" + ClientID, "; $(document).ready(function(){$('table#" + ClientID + "').fixedHeaderTable({ footer: false, cloneHeadToFoot: false, fixedColumn: false });});", true);
```

Now if I test it in FireFox I get

```
.fixedTableHeader is not a function
```

IE9 tells me `method not supported`

I can use FireBug or IE Developer toolbar and see that the script IS loaded?!?!? Any ideas as to why it is not useable??

**EDIT::**
Now I've tried to load the scripts directly in the markup - then it works as intended. But as soon as I try to load them using embedded resources it fails and won't recognize `fixedTableHeader` as a function

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if(jQuery.isFunction($('table#" + ClientID + "').fixedTableHeader)){
      $('table#" + ClientID + "').fixedTableHeader({ height:200, width:'100%' });
    }else{
      alert('unable to load scroll script');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show us the snippet of rendered HTML where the element appears please? My thinking is that your ID that you are trying to match is being constructed differently from what your script is looking for

Comment: Sure @RobAllen - anything that may help to clearify this ;)
The table markup is:
`<table class="grid LRGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" DataKeyField="ID" onselectstart="return false;" border="1" id="grid" style="border-collapse:collapse;table-layout: fixed">`

And the script is rendered like this:
`$(document).ready(function(){$('table#grid').fixedHeaderTable({ footer: false, cloneHeadToFoot: false, fixedColumn: false });});`

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so the error was located in another file... Bummer!

I was already loading jQuery from a BasePage (or someone else did it once ;) )

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
  typeof (WebPageBase), "jQuery", ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"));
```

This conflicted with my control when I tried to load jQuery there... Now I didn't want to remove jQuery initialization from either location. So I decided to make the BasePage load conditional. Since BasePage has knowledge of `LRGrid`, but not the other way around...

So here's the solution:

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(typeof(LRGrid.LRGrid), "jquery"))
      {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
             typeof (WebPageBase), "jQuery", ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"));
      }
```

Hope some of You can use it :-p