# Issue using JQuery in VS 2012 with Master Pages

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a C# web applicaton project with master pages in VS 2012.  I'm using the FixedHeaderTable Jquery plugin with a Gridview since I had success with it in a past project developed in a previous version of visual studio - before Jquery scripts were automatically added.

The error I can't work out as reported in Firefox debugger is TypeError: $(...).fixedHeaderTable is not a function.

It also gives the following warning:  Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

In Site.Master, I include the following:

```
<link href="Styles/defaultTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/myTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.fixedheadertable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And on my Default page, I've added a GridView and am calling the function as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MainContent_GridView1').fixedHeaderTable({ height: 300, themeClass: 'fancyTable' });
}); </script>
```

So far, I have searched here and on Google on the error and tried the suggestions found without luck.  I am able to get the function to work in a stand alone html page, and resurrected my old project which was updated when opening with VS 2012 - it still works, although the code in the SiteMaster has changed significantly.

In [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602534/jquery-plugin-loaded-but-inaccesible-in-webcontrol?s=3%7C0.1929) the person asking has the same issue and provides his own resolution, but I'm not sure if it applies to me - I was loading a previous version of jQuery in Site.Master, but took it out in case there was a conflict.  If I remove the reference to jquery 1.8.2 from Site.Master, I get a reference error - ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

In Firefox I see that the following scripts are loaded:
jquery 1.8.2.js
jquery-ui-1.8.24.js
jqueryfixedheadertable.js
jquery.mousewheel.js

When I highlight the function and hit f12 to go to the source, it opens the fixedheadertable source at the function.

I've been working on this for a few days - can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I had a similar issue. Using full paths in script file references solved it.

Comment: when you access any .net control in Jquery, always use the .ClientID property of that control. .Net change the clientid which is used by jquery. do something like this. '#<%=controlId.ClientID %>'

Comment: @Jigneshk - I saw this mentioned in my research, and the suggestion was to include  ClientIDMode="Static" in the control definition.  It didn't help.  Can you clarfy your suggestion?

Comment: @Sami - the Scripts file is in the root of the site.  Do I not have the full paths in the script references?  They seem to be loaded according th FF debugger.